# rails config.assets.digest defaulting to false in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Clean install of rails 5.0.1

In production `config.assets.digest` is false. (i.e. if I examine the value in the console its false, and the browser can't load the assets because they have the hash strings embedded in them.)

If I add `config.assets.digest = true` to production.rb all is well.

My understanding is that this is supposed to default to true in production?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "acting as if it's false" means? Also, have you tried inspecting the value of `Rails.configuration.assets.digest` from a console running inside the production application?

Comment: Yes its false in the console as well.  See updated question

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on here, OP?